# Lazarus - .wav files playing in sequence

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I'm making a number-to-speech program. I have all of the voice samples all recorded, and working, but every time the input has the numbers in sequential order (012... etc.), it will begin playing the rest of the numbers to 9, against the input.

For example, if 24601 is typed, it will say:

> 2..4..6..0..1..**2..3..4..5..6..7..8..9..0..**

It's not supposed to do that. It will even over-ride the remaining numbers with the sequence, if there are any.

Full code: http://pastebin.com/vFfBRYUu

Here's the offending code block. If you need the remaining pieces, I'll put them up:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  for i := 0 to Length(input.Text) do
  begin
    case var1[i] of
     '0': PlaySound('zero.wav',0,SND_SYNC);
     '1': PlaySound('one.wav',0,SND_SYNC);
     '2': PlaySound('two.wav',0,SND_SYNC);
     '3': PlaySound('three.wav',0,SND_SYNC);
     '4': PlaySound('four.wav',0,SND_SYNC);
     '5': PlaySound('five.wav',0,SND_SYNC);
     '6': PlaySound('six.wav',0,SND_SYNC);
     '7': PlaySound('seven.wav',0,SND_SYNC);
     '8': PlaySound('eight.wav',0,SND_SYNC);
     '9': PlaySound('nine.wav',0,SND_SYNC);
     '-': Delay(400);
     '&': PlaySound('start.wav',0,SND_SYNC);
     '*': PlaySound('call to mess.wav',0,SND_SYNC);
    end;

    Delay(100);
end;
```

The input-to-array:

```
procedure TForm1.inputChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  y := y+1;
  var1[y-1] := input.Text[y]
end;
```

Comment: Where does the `y` come from? Where do you set and update `var1` length?

Comment: @KromStern       
y is an integer used for counting. It increments every time the input changes, to allow the new character from the input to be allocated into a new array entry.

The length of var1 doesn't matter. It's just the array, while the `Length(input.Text);` is for the length. Besides, the bigger block of code is only activated when the user has completed typing.

Comment: If you append to TextLength of chars to `var1` but always play 0..TextLength elements ... do you think that could be your bug? ;-)

Comment: I assume input.text is a string. Then in general starting at 1 would be wise.

Comment: @SopranoAurora: Please do not change/update the question other than making it more clear/precise. This is Q&A site and the question is intended to be self-contained and help other people who have similar problem, irregardless of your program evolution.

Answer (score 3):

`y` variable seems to never reset, which means you append the text to a `var1`. But you play the text-length of elements from `var1` always starting from the 0 element.

```
Input Text | Stored text        | Played text

0123         0123                 0123
876          0123876              012
12345678     012387612345678      01238761
111          012387612345678111   012
```

Sounds like a bug.

Also there is number of mistakes:

- Seeing it always plays much too many numbers, `input.Text` length is not reset properly
- You iterate over `input.Text` but you play from `var1` variable. You should **always** iterate and access the same array/string!
- The loop should be `for i := 1 to Length(input.Text) do` if you iterate over a string
- Relying on hidden knowledge of text start position in `var1`
- Might be just your example, but you haven't closed the `for` loop with a `end;`
- Meaningless / non-speaking variable names
- Formatting (I have fixed it in your question, plz check)

You might also do some debugging on your own, to isolate the bug, by outputting the `var1` to display before "speaking" it. E.g. by `ShowMessage(var1)` or alike;

Comment: Oh, Sorry. I forgot to mention that var1 is from a seperate block of code used to make the input a char array. I'll add that in.

Comment: Please verify and add that, cos it seems to be the cause of the bug.

Comment: @SopranoAurora: Appended.

Comment: The `y` variable should not reset. It's for indexing the new inputs into the array `var1`. `i` is used in the main code block as the counter.

Comment: @SopranoAurora: If you insist on that, then the loop should be `for i := y to y + Length(Input.Text)`. Which is awful design by the way - to use so many variables interchangeably coupled around the place.

Comment: I think I'm being a bit vague here... sorry about that.

If you need to see all of the code, it's here: http://pastebin.com/vFfBRYUu

Comment: @SopranoAurora: I'll update my answer to pinpoint the bug in your code. If you are interested in discussing your code we can do that in Skype perhaps. kromster80